# realtime.schema_migrations does not exist

Tags: supabase

I am running the `SUPABASE_SCANNER_BUFFER_SIZE=200MB supabase start` command after dumping my production db from `supabase` with the flag `--column-inserts` the problem is that is returning this error when i run the supabase start command: `ERROR: relation "realtime.schema_migrations" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01).`

I've been following docs: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/managing-environments#set-up-a-local-environment

```
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Recv: {"Type":"ReadyForQuery","TxStatus":"I"}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Send: {"Type":"Parse","Name":"","Query":"INSERT INTO realtime.schema_migrations (version, inserted_at) VALUES (20230228184745, '2023-03-04  18:48:30')","ParameterOIDs":null}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Send: {"Type":"Describe","ObjectType":"S","Name":""}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Send: {"Type":"Sync"}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Recv:   {"Type":"ErrorResponse","Severity":"ERROR","SeverityUnlocalized":"ERROR","Code":"42P01","Message":"relation \"realtime.schema_migrations\" does not exist","Detail":"","Hint":"","Position":13,"InternalPosition":0,"InternalQuery":"","Where":"","SchemaName":"","TableName":"","ColumnName":"","DataTypeName":"","ConstraintName":"","File":"parse_relation.c","Line":1371,"Routine":"parserOpenTable","UnknownFields":null}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Recv: {"Type":"ReadyForQuery","TxStatus":"I"}
2023/03/20 01:17:35 PG Send: {"Type":"Terminate"}
Error: ERROR: relation "realtime.schema_migrations" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
```

The `realtime.schema_migrations table` is in the `seed.sql` file

```
CREATE TABLE realtime.schema_migrations (
 version bigint NOT NULL,
 inserted_at timestamp(0) without time zone
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `supabase db dump --data-only` ? There are many flags that we pass to pg_dump to ignore managed schemas, including realtime. When developing locally, the realtime schema will be provisioned by the CLI so dumping it again is not necessary.

Comment: Hi yes I used data only flag I don’t have a clue how to ignore a table when dumping the database 